# Wrap left box text around right float, keep markup semantic, IE>=8

Tags: html, css

What we want:

```
div a text div a text  | div b text |
div a text div a text  | div b text |
div a text div a text  | div b text |
div a text div a text div a text diva
div a text div a text div a text diva
div a text div a text div a text diva
```

What we have:

```
<div id="a">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>

<div id="b">
    <h3>...</h3>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

If the order of the content in the two div's **must remain in the order given** (note that content is variable), how is it possible to achieve what we want (and work in IE8...)?

`Div b` is of a fixed width, variable height, and the container div of `div a` and `div b` is of a fixed width.

**EDIT 1**

I've discovered the technique of inserting a dummy div above `div a`, setting it's width to that of `div b`, using JS to calculate height of `div b` and applying that to the dummy div, floating the dummy div right, then absolutely positioning `div b` on top of the dummy div. It's the only way I've found that maintains the order of the content in `div a` and `div b` without using advanced CSS3...

Comment: Can you swap the order of div1 and div2 around? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VAeHq/)

Comment: if you can swap order of the divs, this is easy. Also -- please note that a plain numeric value is invalid for `id`, so `id="1"`as per the code in the question is not valid.

Comment: Guys, no re-ordering of divs. Thanks for the info on numerics Spudley, I've edited my post to reflect.

Answer (score -1):

Adjust the following example to your desired widths: http://cdpn.io/heDJu